# views::cartesian_product - how to do same vector N times?

Tags: c++, c++23

This code works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
 
int main()
{
    const auto y = std::vector{1, 2, 3};    

    for (int i{1}; auto const &[a, b, c] : std::views::cartesian_product(y, y, y))
        std::cout << "(" << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << ')' << (i++ % 3 ? " " : "\n");
    
}
```

And produces the output

```
$ g++-12-master --std=c++23 cartesian.cpp -o cartesian.exe && ./cartesian.exe
(1 1 1) (1 1 2) (1 1 3)
(1 2 1) (1 2 2) (1 2 3)
(1 3 1) (1 3 2) (1 3 3)
(2 1 1) (2 1 2) (2 1 3)
(2 2 1) (2 2 2) (2 2 3)
(2 3 1) (2 3 2) (2 3 3)
(3 1 1) (3 1 2) (3 1 3)
(3 2 1) (3 2 2) (3 2 3)
(3 3 1) (3 3 2) (3 3 3)
```

Is there syntax where I can pass in the `const auto y = std::vector{1, 2, 3};` once and specify an integer (in this case 3)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `N` can be a template parameter, you can populate a call to `std::views::cartesian_product` in a pack expansion:

```
template <size_t N>
auto product(auto&& v)
{
    return [&v]<size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
        { return std::views::cartesian_product((Is, v)...); }
        (std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

[See it live](https://godbolt.org/z/T98h4h9oP)

Comment: Just `(Is, v)...`, which as an added bonus means you're doing a product over the same vector and not `N` copies of it.

Comment: @Barry what would change?

Comment: @Bob Instead of needing the lambda `f` and calling `cartesian_product(f(Is)...)`, just call `cartesian_product((Is, v)...)`

Comment: @Barry Why does the godbolt link have `I` in `auto f = [&](size_t I){ return v; };`?

Comment: I was wondering why a view to flatten nested loops is missing.

Comment: Hmm. it seems that `views::cartesian_product` is taking ownership here. Is this new behaviour over range-v3? Also [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/T98h4h9oP) for Barry's suggestion

Comment: @Red.Wave `cartesian_product` does flatten nested loops. Generally you know how deep the nesting is, so `cartesian_product(y, y, y)` isn't really worse than `product<3>(y)`

Comment: @Caleth, no arguments. I really wanted to see `cartesian_product` in the std , but couldn't come up with a good name.